# Is the evolute always a regular curve?

Tags: plane-curves, plane-geometry

Is the evolute always a regular curve? (that is, the tangent vector of this curve is nonzero at any time)

Comment: What is a regular curve ?

Answer (score 0):

Evolutes in plane (equation  y= x + R  **n** where **n** is normal vector) have a cusp at point of symmetry in smooth continuous curves as radius of curvature R is a maximum or minimum with third order derivative vanishing.